# how to scrape preformatted text from a html page into a csv file?

Tags: python, selenium, download

I am using selenium to automate a protocol for getting information from http://curie.utmb.edu/getarea.html where the results are presented as text on the page. Since the data is preformatted text and not a table I dont know how to get the resulting data into a csv file.

The result looks like:
[Screenshot of the result page with its source code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZG4gL.png)

Any help getting this information would be appreciated

Comment: please share the code you have written so far.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer to my problem, just posting it here incase it is helpful for someone else.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "lxml")
    prelist = soup.find_all('pre')
    info = []
    for pre in prelist:
        info.append(pre.text)
with open ('getarea.txt', 'w') as file:
    for i in info:
       file.write('\n'+ i)
with open ('getarea.txt') as fin, open( 'file_name.csv', 'w') as fout:
        o=csv.writer(fout)
        for line in fin:
            o.writerow(line.split())
```